# Core dump of main application on small embedded system

Tags: linux, arm, coredump

I'm trying to dump the core of a segfaulting main application on a small embedded system running on Linux. The main application essentially handles the complete execution and functionality of the device, and causes the system to reboot upon receiving a `SIGSEGV` signal.

I have made sure that:

- the core dump is allowed to be of unlimited size

  - `ulimit -c unlimited`
- an output path to a writeable directory with sufficient free space (mounted SD-card) is set

  - `sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern='/path/to/dir/core_%e.%p'`
- I have permission to read and execute the binary

I have tried to dump the core of a dummy process like so:

```
sleep 10 &
killall -SIGSEGV sleep
```

And it works as expected, generating a core dump of the process at the desired location.

However, the main application does not create a core dump and just causes the system to reboot. I have tried segfaulting the application both manually though my telnet-provided shell, as well as exploiting a stack buffer overflow remotely (which is what I'm trying to investigate).

Since this is a small embedded system, I don't have access to common utilities such as gdb, ptrace, pstack etc.

Is there any workaround here that would allow me to view the stack of the process, either while still running or after receiving a `SIGSEGV` signal?

Comment: did you try to send some other signals than `SIGSEGV`?  E.g. `SIGILL`  or `SIGEMT`?

Comment: Yes, I went through all of the relevant signals.

Comment: Sounds like an intentional watchdog feature to get the system back up when the process crashes

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. But wouldn't it still be expected to generate a dump at the time of the crash?

Comment: I see two reasons; 1) program disables `ulimit -c` itself (see `/proc/<pid>/limits`) and 2) program catches all signals to exit "cleanly"

Comment: Is the application suid? Suid programs refuse to coredump for security reasons.

Comment: @ensc Might be the reason, I'll look into it.

Comment: @EOF No, it's not.

Comment: If you want to be able to see the stack, did you try reading from `/proc/[pid]/mem` (probably after `SIGSTOP`)?

Comment: @EOF Any idea how to do that? `cat /proc/[pid]/mem` just throws me a `read error: Input/output error`.

Comment: @proah I'd recommend starting with `man proc` and looking at what it says about permissions.

Comment: @EOF Yeah, as specified in the original post I don't have access to ptrace and hence no ability to attach to the process to gain permission.

Comment: @proah What does `ptrace` have to do with having the right userid?